# How to get Button location of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

As titled, I want to make my application more user friendly by moving the mouse to the OK or Cancel button automatically (I got got affected some game...).

I know first thing I need is get the MainWindow application location, then + the location of the Button.

But how to do I get the location if the button is inside a Grid not Canvas?  And if the Button is contains inside another control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `Button b`
You could use [`b.PointToScreen(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx) to get a specific point on the button into screen coordinates.